# How to atomically set the value of the file attribute in java?

Tags: java, atomic, file-attributes

I need to atomically set the value of the file attribute in java. I found the method

```
Path Files.setAttribute(Path path, String attribute, Object value, LinkOption... options)
```

but the documentation is not specified that the value will be set atomically.
Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean with atomically in this context? When dealing with file-systems it's best not to make any assumptions since files can be changed by other processes at any time.

Comment: When I change the attribute I have to be sure that at any given time only one process modifies it

Answer (score 1):

FileLock could be a solution:

```
    Path path = new File("C:/Test/test.txt").toPath();

    FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
    FileLock lock = fc.tryLock();
    if (lock != null) {
        try {
            FileTime fileTime = FileTime.fromMillis(0);
            Files.setAttribute(path, "basic:creationTime", fileTime, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
        } finally {
            lock.release();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If one goes this way, be sure to read the FileLock API docs. They are more of a suggestion, rather than an assertion. Oh, and the lock is for the JVM, not the thread currently running. So don't try to do stuff with multiple threads and assume atomicity.